# How to optimize direct path insert (into subpartition)?

Tags: oracle, insert, partitioning, jobs, dml

We are using Direct-Path approach to fill one of our Data Marts. We are also pointing the exact subpartition to which insert should be done. Here is the sql:

```
INSERT /*+ APPEND_VALUES */ INTO DWH.DM_CORE_AC_SALDOS SUBPARTITION(SYS_SUBP7709) VALUES (:B1 ,:B2 ,:B3 ,:B4 ,:B5 ,:B6 ,:B7 ,:B8 ,:B9 ,:B10 ,:B11 ,:B12 ,:B13 ,:B14 ,:B15 ,:B16 ,:B17 ,:B18 ,:B19 ,:B20 ,:B21 )
```

All process is controlled by dbms_parallel_execute with parallel level of 40. That is there are 40 separate sessions doing their own insert to separate subpartitions. However, the process is taking too long to finish, in sessions windows we can see that sessions are not locking each other, but they have wait class 'User I/O' and wait state 'WAITING' .  Here is the snapshot of how sessions windows looks during the process:

[image]

Is there anything we are doing wrong? Maybe we should have set some database parameters right or changed a table structure (initrans or pctfree) ?

Edit : Almost all sessions have event 'db file sequential read'. I suppose reason why it is running slow may be because of an index maintenance operations. I checked file# from dba_data_files and most of the show files allocated for index tablespace. I read that direct path insert does index maintanance in the end of insert so may be this is a problem. In this case should I avoid using direct path insert?

Comment: Why do you use `insert ... values ...` instead of select statement?

Comment: You need to provide the actual wait event. "User I/O" is a generalized class, not the event itself.  And I agree with astentx, you should use INSERT SELECT (in pdml & append) rather than INSERT VALUES. There shouldn't be need to use dbms_parallel_execute to handle this.

Comment: @astentx, we are using insert .. values because all values to be inserted are gathered into a nested collection  from various tables and views inside a loop, after that ,  collection values are inserted into a table in one forall statement

Answer (score 2):

Using direct path writes [takes exclusive locks on the corresponding table/partitions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/managing-tables.html#GUID-2E573512-51EA-4470-894A-C4BA20593273). Only one session at a time can do direct-path writes on an object.

Running 40 parallel processes won't help here. You're running 40 transactions one after the other. If you want to use direct path writes, you're better off running it all the same transaction; ditch dbms_parallel_execute.

Comment: How can you tell from that screen shot that they are running one after another? They could be, but I don't see how you can tell definitively. Also, direct path writes lock at the segment level; since the OP is using partition extended syntax, only the specific segment (partition) is locked.

Comment: @Sherzodbek, where is the data coming from? Unless you are doing array binds, you are essentially doing row by row inserts, defeating what you are trying the achieve.

Comment: @BobC, yes, that is exactly what i was hoping to achieve. We are aware that only one session at a time can do a direct path insert into a table, but if we can specifiy partition or subpartition, as far as i know, only that partition will be locked so I can run multiple jobs that will do an insert to their corresponding partitions locking only that partition without having to wait each other. Data comes from various tables and are gathered into one nested collection inside a loop by using  .Extend and then when all rows are gathered in that collection, we use forall that does direct path insert

Comment: @BobC, dbms_parallel_execute task has level of 40 , all 40 sessions will call the same procedure but will pass  different values(partition keys like department code) and then using those values we identify to which partition we should insert. I have tested this scenario with other tables, without specifiying partitions and using direct path inserts, yes, we have valid blocking sessions, which will prove that only one session can do direct path insert, whole table gets locked. But when we specified partitions , then we don't see any blocking sessions and only partitions are locked.

Comment: @BobC, in the above case in screen shot, we still don't see blocking sessions, in v$locked_object we can find that only table subpartitions are locked. However all process is taking too long. I had to specifiy that total number of rows being inserted into a table is 90 mln, maybe that is the reason, but i am not sure

Comment: @BobC true - I just assumed that some/all the sessions are writing to the same subpartition. @Sherzodbek - you'll need to give more details about what exactly the code is doing in this process. Either way, I would still avoid DIY parallelizing single row direct path inserts. You're likely to encounter blocking sessions at some point & single row inserts are one of the slowest ways to load data. You should be looking at bulk processing (`forall insert`) or `insert ... select`.

Comment: @ChrisSaxon, thanks for the insight. Yes, I am using  bulk colect and then `forall insert ` with specifying partition name and giving APPEND_VALUES hint.

Comment: Almost all sessions have event 'db file sequential read'. I suppose reason why it is running slow may be because of an index maintenance operations. I checked file# from dba_data_files and most of the show files allocated for index tablespace. I read that direct path insert does index maintanance in the end of insert so may be this is a problem. In this case should I avoid using direct path insert?